# ARC and viewDidUnload

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

If I have a strong reference to a view in my view hierarchy, do I have to set it to nil in viewDidUnload or is it taken care of by ARC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is so much misinformation in the two earlier answers I'm going to clarify exactly what the situation is. Note that these are relative to the DEPLOYMENT target, not to whether you use the iOS6 SDK to build):

- you don't worry about self.view - the UIViewController manages that
- top level objects - ie those NOT contained in another object - must be strong
- other objects should use weak (the system nil's the ivar when they are released preventing crashes from trying to use a released object)
- for Deployment on pre-iOS6 devices, use viewDidUnload to release top level objects and anything else you want to. NOTE: dealloc is NOT called after this - the next message you get may well be viewDidLoad, when the memory problem that caused the message goes away and the view reappears)
- for iOS6 and later, don't use viewDidUnload (see edit below), use didReceiveMemoryWarning if you want to free memory not related to views or the other UI objects.
- dealloc is called in all releases. With ARC, you don't call super, and you don't release memory as you did in the old days.

EDIT: From the iOS6 SDK UIViewController class description:

> viewDidUnload 
>   Called when the controller’s view is released from
>   memory. (Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under
>   low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.)

What Apple does do is remove the backing store - the cached pixels. They found this removed most of the consumed memory, and that viewDidUnload was poorly implemented (they told us this at WWDC 2012).

Comment: voted for useful situation analysis . BTW, do you mean don't use `viewDidUnload` for iOS6 and later?

Comment: @Carina, can you be more specific? I'll try to make bullet item 5 clearer now.

Comment: tip 5 says viewDidLoad but should say viewDidUnload

Comment: Uh it says viewDidUnload. Bullet 4 says viewDidLoad which is correct.

Comment: I find your answer helpful, being new to iOS it seems to go against what I'm learning. While reading [Beginning iOS 5 Development](http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iOS-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430236051) it told me how important `viewDidUnload` is. I found Xcode did not generate this in new projects. I'm puzzled how to get Xcode when targeting prior iOS 5 to generate code for the right target platform? Also, when I add an outlet it defaults to weak, I had just been accepting the default. I have `iOS Deployment Target` set to 6.0 at the project level.

Comment: Consider it an oversight if Apple's template does not generate them for 5.1. Those methods WILL be called in 5.1, but not in iOS6. So if you use a deployment target of 5.1, they get called in 5.1 but not when your code runs in 6.0 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ivar that has a `strong` reference to an object then that object will hang around for as long as that ivar points to it.

So yes you need to set the pointer to `nil` or your strong reference will keep the view alive. If the view is being loaded from a nib and it is not the `rootView` then it is recommended to use `weak` so that you don't have to worry about this issue.

Comment: Why do I need to set it to nil? Right after viewDidUnload, dealloc is called and the reference is set to nll by itself

Comment: dealloc isn't aways necessarily called right after viewDidUnload.  It is a dubious method, and that's part of the reason Apple deprecated it in iOS 6.  Basically, the system is trying to free up memory, so you should manually nil anything that you can live without for a while in that method (pretty much the same as didReceiveMemoryWarning)

Comment: @borrrden dealloc deprecated in iOS6? -_- Can you link me? When do we release malloc-ed stuff then?

Comment: No, `-viewDidUnload` was deprecated. `-dealloc` was not.

Comment: @0xSina What Jonathan said above